# Is there REST API to trigger a file transfer/import job/program?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, soap-api

Is there any way I can avoid having to travel back in time to use SOAP and instead use the REST api to:
1) Trigger a file transfer
2) Trigger an import job
3) or Trigger a program
?

I believe the answer is No, but I'm just double checking...

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the answer is no.  Maybe someday, but not today.

You do have another option that may be more appealing.  You can set up Automations in Automation Studio to do all the stuff you listed.  You can set these up to be triggered upon a file drop to the ET FTP site.  Have a look [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/triggered_automations/).